# Iterating over a custom collection of objects and deleting duplicates

Tags: c#, loops

I have custom collection class that holds a specific custom object. The object class is called `TestReport` and the collection class which holds these objects is called `TestReports` and it inherits `System.Collections.CollectionBase`. `TestReport` contains the property `LocalReportID` and `ScoreTypeID`. What I want to do is iterate through the collection of objects and remove any duplicates, which in my case means that the `ScoreTypeID` and `LocalReportID` are the same between objects. What I have so far leaves out objects and doesn't do the job properly, and I am quite stumped as to the solution. Note here that each time there is a duplicate, I take the object and place it in another collection before I remove the duplicates. I'm not set on doing this, it was just my idea, but if there is a better way of accomplishing it, please let me know:

```
TestReports objTestReportsContainer = new TestReports();
foreach (TestReport objTestReport in objTestReports)
{
    objTestReportsContainer.Add(objTestReport);
}
objTestReports.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < objTestReportsContainer.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int k = objTestReportsContainer.Count - 1; k > 0; k--)
    {
        if ((objTestReportsContainer.Item(k).LocalReportID == objTestReportsContainer.Item(i).LocalReportID) &&
            (objTestReportsContainer.Item(k).ScoreTypeID == objTestReportsContainer.Item(i).ScoreTypeID) &&
            (objTestReportsContainer.Item(k).LocalReportID != 0))
            {
                objTestReports.Add(objTestReportsContainer.Item(k));
                objTestReportsContainer.Remove(objTestReportsContainer.Item(i));
                objTestReportsContainer.Remove(objTestReportsContainer.Item(k));
            }
            else if ((objTestReportsContainer.Item(k).ScoreTypeID == objTestReportsContainer.Item(i).ScoreTypeID) &&
                     (objTestReportsContainer.Item(k).LocalReportID == 0) && 
                     (objTestReportsContainer.Item(i).LocalReportID == 0))
            {
                objTestReports.Add(objTestReportsContainer.Item(k));
                objTestReportsContainer.Remove(objTestReportsContainer.Item(i));
                objTestReportsContainer.Remove(objTestReportsContainer.Item(k));
            }
     }
}
```

The original items were populated in `objTestReports` and I moved them over to `objTestReportsContainer` so I could do all the work with that collection and add the final filtered collection back to `objTestReports`. This code seems to leave some items out every time and I can't find a solution. Any better way to solve this problem?

**EDIT** I forgot to note that in the if statements I separate between whether or not LocalReportID is 0 or not because if it is the TestReport object is considered an average report and if it isn't 0 its a band report. Just for clarification, but probably not important to how the iteration flow should work.

**EDIT 2** As requested here is my definition of `TestReports`. The mode `UIGetLocalTestReports` is just what I call to fill the the collection with `TestReport` obejcts.

```
public class TestReports : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
    public TestReports()
    {
        //constructor?
        List.Clear();
    }

    public void Add(TestReport objTestReport)
    {
        // add a testReport to the testReports collection
        List.Add(objTestReport);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        // remove a testReport from the testReports collection
        if (index <= Count - 1 && index >= 0)
        {
            List.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(TestReport objTestReport)
    {
        //remove a TestReport from the collection without passing an index
        List.Remove(objTestReport);
    }

    public TestReport Item(int Index)
    {
        //get the item requested and explicitly cast to the testSubject type
        return (TestReport)List[Index];
    }

    public void UIGetLocalTestReports(SqlConnection mySqlConn, int intTestTypeID)
    {
        //clear list
        List.Clear();

        if (mySqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand("StatsGen_UI_ByTest_GetReports", mySqlConn);
            myComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@intTestTypeID", intTestTypeID));
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = myComm.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    TestReport objTestReport;
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        objTestReport = new TestReport();
                        objTestReport.TestReportID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        objTestReport.TestReportName = dr.GetString(1);
                        objTestReport.SummaryDataSP = dr.GetString(2);
                        objTestReport.ScoreTypeID = dr.GetInt32(3);
                        if (dr.GetValue(4) != DBNull.Value)
                            objTestReport.LocalReportID = dr.GetInt32(4);
                        else
                            objTestReport.LocalReportID = 0;
                        List.Add(objTestReport);
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                //TODO: Add some error handling here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this code gets you closer:

```
var keepers =
    objTestReports
        .Cast<TestReport>()
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.LocalReportID, x.ScoreTypeID })
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .ToArray();

objTestReports.Clear();

foreach (var objTestReport in keepers)
{
    objTestReports.Add(objTestReport);
}
```

Comment: This code seems good except I am getting an error on the Group By, which says that objTestReports does not contain a definition for GroupBy

Comment: Does your custom object implement `IEnumerable<TestReport>`? If not it will work if you do implement it.

Comment: oh no it implements `System.Collections.CollectionBase`. I will change that see the results

Comment: It sort of opens up a whole new can of worms in many other places that I would prefer to not have to change. Is there any way to do this without using LINQ?

Comment: You sure can. You can implement the appropriate method signatures to allow the linq operations directly on the custom collection. Can you post the code for `TestReports` and I'll see what I can do?

Comment: Alright I posted the definition of the TestReports class in edit 2.

Comment: @RyanGray - That was easy - since you based your code on `CollectionBase` all that was required was a `.Cast<TestReport>()` to make it work with LINQ. I'd suggest you think about basing your collection on `List<TestReport>` instead though as you get better type safety.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for your help. I will definitely keep in mind and employ what you have said in previous projects

Answer (score 0):

You can call `objTestReports.OfType<TestReport>()` to get an `IEnumerable<TestReport>` and work with LINQ going forward.

The you can use the Distinct extension method to get your distinct items.

```
IEnumerable<TestReport> reportsAsEnumerable = objTestReports.OfType<TestReport>().Distinct();
```

If TestReport does not implement IEquatable you should either implement it, or use a custom IEqualityComparer (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)